# Sqlite No column issue when migrating from version 3 to 4

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Users are facing issues when migrating from version 3 to 4 in Android Sqlite Database and the issue is not able to reproduce on the development side, it is just posted to Firebase crashes. In version 4 we added the Room database and before that, we were using SQliteDatabase. Some tables had data types that were not supported in Room. So renamed the existing table and copied values to a new table with the same name as version 3.

Please find the exception below:

Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException

```
Fatal Exception: f.a.x.d: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling  | android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: column15 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_name (
_id,
column1 ,
column2 ,
column3 ,
column4 ,
column5 ,
column6 ,
column7 ,
column8 ,
column9 ,
column10 ,
column11 ,
column12 ,
column13 ,
column14 ,
<truncated: 9039 chars>
at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:79)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:102)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableToList$ToListSubscriber.onError(FlowableToList.java:79)
at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onError(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:101)
at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.EmptySubscription.error(EmptySubscription.java:55)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate.subscribeActual(FlowableGenerate.java:48)
at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableToList.subscribeActual(FlowableToList.java:44)
at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14882)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Your code does not have enough to go on.  You're using React with RXJava?  It doesn't sound like a Room issue.

Comment: Look like a wrong migration from v3 to v4

Comment: Hi thanks for the response...The user has reported issue is happening when they migrate and exception comes when they open the application and points to migrate (3_4) in RoomDatabase.
Its working in debug build if we try to update from version 3 to version 4..

Comment: Currently using Rx java for DB queries and when we moved some class to kotlin we are using coroutines there..